# Vim match multiple argument Latex commands

Tags: vim, latex, syntax-highlighting

I would like to know how to match a Latex command with multiple arguments in Vim. For example, I would like to match things of the form:

```
\command{SOME LATEX}{SOME LATEX}{SOME LATEX}
```

where the 'SOME LATEX' parts can have any normal latex highlighted inside. e.g.,

```
\command{\anothercommand{a}}{\anothercommand{b}}{\command{a}{b}{c}}
```

I am particularly interested in matching the `\command{`, each `}{`, and the final `}`. Is this possible in Vim, and if so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer dealing with two argument cases, from which one can extend to higher arity cases. It deals with displaying `\braket{a}{b}` as `<a|b>` by using Vim's conceal functionality.

```
" This matches the '\braket' portion and displays it as '<'
syn match texStatement "\\braket\s*{\@=" conceal cchar=< contained containedin=@texmathzones

" This matches the first set of braces and hides the first, displaying the second as '|'.
syn region braketInner matchgroup=Delimiter start=+\%(\\braket\)\@<={+ end="}" contained transparent containedin=@texMathZones concealends cchar=|

" This matches the second set of braces and hides the first, displaying the second as '>'.
syn region braketInner matchgroup=Delimiter start=+\%(\\braket.*}\)\@<={+ end="}" contained transparent containedin=@texMathZones concealends cchar=>
```

Unfortunately, this means that braket commands cannot be contained in themselves; I cannot find a workaround for this.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's no easy task, and the complexity of it will greatly depends on how strong you want it to be...

I just wrote those functions, which build a regular expression for you:

```
function! RecursiveBuild(nb)
    if a:nb <= 0
        return '[^}]\{-}'
    endif
    return '\([^{]\|{'.RecursiveBuild(a:nb-1).'}\)\{-}'
endfunction
function! BuildRegex(command, nb)
    return '\\'.a:command.'\(\zs{\ze' . RecursiveBuild(5) . '}\)\{'.a:nb.'}'
endfunction
```

Then, you just have to run:

```
:let @/ = BuildRegex('command', 2)
```

To highlight the opening curvy brace of the 2nd group

If you want to match something else, you only need to move the `\zs` (start of capture) and `\ze` (end of capture) in the `BuildRegex` function

### Screenshots

Here are some examples:

[image: demo1]

[image: demo2]

#### Disclaimer

This will only handle 5 levels of calls, meaning:

```latex
# This works:
\command1{\command2{\command3{\command4{\command5{Hey there}}}}}

# This doesn't works:
\command1{\command2{\command3{\command4{\command5{\command6{Hey there}}}}}}
```

You can increase the supported level by changing the argument given to the `RecursiveBuild` function, but at some point, the regex will be too big and vim won't like it. I can go up to 8 personally.